# ERC20 pegged to Fiat

Tags: erc-20

I have seen various projects linking tokens to Fiat currency to maintain some stability. This link has some commentary - https://themerkle.com/what-is-a-pegged-cryptocurrency/.

For ERC20 has anyone any idea how this can done?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? If yes, could you share how you did it.

Answer (score 1):

For our presale at Etherparty, we peg our tokens at $0.10 each, and accept ETH for the sale. How we did it: record the price of Ether from the Coinmarketcap api at the time of your transaction initiation, and then can calculate the dollar value of the Ethereum sent from that. You can then send back the appropriate amount of tokens.

Comment: But how do you ensure stability? If ETH/USD moved a lot, then what happens? It means you have to issue more tokens? When you issue more then the reverse affect can happen, that existing token holders can lose money. I am unsure how that method will work. It seems to me you will just issue more and more tokens to stop losses and then the tokens will be worth less and less over time.

Comment: The coin is worth 10 cent on our platform. It doesn't matter about stability, we force the stability by saying it is worth 10 cents. We don't just issue more, we have an ICO with a specific amount, as written in the whitepaper. No bonus tokens are issued.

Comment: The token has some meaning in the actual project so there has to be a balance between fiat and project market dynamics. I am unsure how your proposal would work.

Comment: @diabetesjones Did all this happen via a contract or were you collecting buys via a front-end and then manually sending tokens to buyers? edit: also, amazing handle.

Comment: How did you go about setting up the front end? and how did you send the tokens? Just have buyers send ETH to a contract and then look at the emitted logging events to see who bought how much, and at what price? and then put all that in a function to transfer the amounts to specific addresses?